# How to autorefresh every 1 minute a single div in single post wordpress with inner page template

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, partial-page-refresh, wordpress

How to setup an div to auto refresh?
I use Transcript theme for wordpress, in single.php is on call for inner php page:

```
</div><!-- /innerLeft -->

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/innerNarrowSidebar.php'); ?>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/innerWideSidebar.php'); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

The code inside **innerNarrowSidebar.php**

```
<?php if($trns_options['enArc'] == 1) { ?>
        <div class="widget">
            <h3 class="widget_sTitle_b"><?php _e('Archives','Transcript'); ?></h3>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

And than in **innerpage_120x600.php**

I have some google adsense

`**NOTE**`: I added this code in innerNarrowSidebar.php  but dosn't work , the div dosn't autorefresh
There is the code that i have added:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
setInterval( "SANAjax();", 10000 );  ///////// 10 seconds 
$(function() {
SANAjax = function(){

$('#narrowSidebar').fadeOut("slow").load('ads/innerpage_120x600.php').fadeIn("slow");

}
 });
</script>
```

If this is not possible, how to make an text widget to auto refresh?

Comment: Change to `setInterval(SANAjax, 10000);`

Comment: and call it inside `$(function(){});` just after `SANAjax` declaration

Comment: @dfsq i have tryed but nothing check it:
http://www.videoshqip.tv/?p=387  NOTE: if you are logged on Facebook you have to accept the app to be able to see the post, just logout and try again to see the page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in comments:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

$j(function($) {
var SANAjax = function(){
  //Add here anticache modificator:
  var rnd=Math.random();
  $('#narrowSidebar').fadeOut("slow").load('ads/innerpage_120x600.php?nc='+rnd).fadeIn("slow");

}
setInterval(SANAjax, 10000 );  ///////// 10 seconds 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I added this over <div id="narrowSidebar"> in innerNarrowSidebar.php , but still no changes :( , thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry I would not register your appin facebook, extract problem and back to us

Comment: Just logout from facebook!

Comment: jquery is loaded but it is not used as $

Comment: http://www.videoshqip.tv/wp-content/themes/TranscriptV1RC2/ads/innerpage_120x600.php is javascript ? you not need to reload it each time!

Comment: as you used `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` you have to use `$j` for all jQuery calls, see updated answer

Comment: What do you think, is this OK with adsense tos ?
I saw that you understand very well javascript, so can you check for me why my ads dosn't apear on home page, they worked before but now no, sometime they don't appear in single post:
NO ADS here:
http://www.videoshqip.tv/?p=1098
ADS OK:
http://www.videoshqip.tv/?p=1032

Comment: This is giving just fadeout effect but this is not refreshing the DIV :( >> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

$j(function($) {
var SANAjax = function(){
  //Add here anticache modificator:
  var rnd=Math.random();
  $('#narrowSidebar').fadeOut("slow").load('ads/innerpage_120x600.php?nc='+rnd).fadeIn("slow");

}
setInterval(SANAjax, 30000 );  
 });
</script>

Comment: you should call google api instead of reload init script each time, but this is far out of this question.

Comment: what do you mean @eicto to call google api instead to reload init script?

Comment: I mean, that your AD div loads some google ad, i think you can ask google to refresh AD in element, no reason to load script same scipt again and again [this is load script](http://www.videoshqip.tv/wp-content/themes/TranscriptV1RC2/ads/innerpage_120x600.php) [this is the script](http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js), you have to run some google's api method to refresh ad, not need to reload loader

Comment: I can see ads, but i want they to rerfresh for example evey 30 seconds, not the whole page but just that div where are ads , or maybe if is that possible because this div call an php file , inside of that file ads.php to refresh itselfs but inside a div!

Comment: ads.php provides javascript link... you should just calljs function instead of load...